# Lazy load / configure a class to inherit from

Tags: python, python-2.7, lazy-loading, multiple-inheritance

I created a Python package with an optional part / class. When I use this optional part (OptClass) I have to change the inheritance of a class (ExampleClass). Now I use this code :

```
if use_option :
    _opt_class =  __import__('package.my_module', globals(), locals(), ['OptClass']).OptClass
else :
    _opt_class = object # do not use the optional class

....

class ExampleClass(base_module.BaseHandler, _opt_class):

    ....
```

Is there another Pythonic way to solve this? For instance using dynamic inheritance or layzy loading, or ...?

Comment: The pythonic way would be just to inherit from the class and disable the unwanted behaviour by checking the `use_option` flag dynamically. (Or some other way that abuses inheritance less, like the Strategy pattern.)

Comment: But than a lot of code and api libs will be loaded, which will not be used for this configuration.

Comment: Code should load fairly quickly from `.pyc`s, no? Anyway, in that case what you do is fine I guess, although i'd use the much simpler `from package.my_module import OptClass` and `OptClass=object` instead. (I'd still consider encapsulating the difference into a property of `ExampleClass` instead of making the inheritance chain variable though.)

Comment: Changing a class's definition at runtime in itself is not "Pythonic": It drastically reduces readability and overall "grok-ability".

Comment: Have you measured the impact on your package when you load the extra libraries? Eg, memory and time wise? I'm inclined to say that if the option is there, the necessary stuff should always be loaded.

Comment: This class / package has a lot of dependencies like : oauth2client, uritemplate, httplib2 and apiclient. All part of the python oauth2 client library, which I sometimes do not need at all; which do not have to be a part of the project if this option is not used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably use a class decorator:

```
def optional_inherit(cls):
    if use_option:
        from package.my_module import OptClass
        class ExampleClassWithOptClass(cls, OptClass):
            pass
        return ExampleClassWithOptClass
    else:
        return cls

...

@optional_inherit
class ExampleClass(base_module.BaseHandler):
    ...
```

If you're doing this a lot, you could write `optional_inherit` to take arguments; in this case, `@optional_inherit(use_option, 'package.mymodule.OptClass')`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to add some extra behaviour to `ExampleClass` based on `use_option`. I would just write two classes (one derived from the other with extra behaviour added), then use a generic name to point to one of the classes depending on the `use_option`:

```
from package.my_module import OptClass

class SimpleExampleClass(base_module.BaseHandler):
    pass

class ExtendedExampleClass(SimpleExampleClass, OptClass):
    pass

ExampleClass = ExtendedExampleClass if use_option else SimpleExampleClass
```

This way, you don't even need to add extra functionality in `ExtendedExampleClass`: it's all in `OptClass` already.

(Perhaps this is the strategy pattern millimoose mentioned; I wouldn't really know.)

Comment: Still a lot of code will be loaded. Is it possible to lazy load OptClass or ExtendedExampleClass?

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider modeling this modularity explicitly. You mention OAuth2, so for the sake of the example I'll assume the functionality you want to add is authentication using that protocol.

Then you'd have files like:

#### `authmodule.py`

```
import oauth2client
# ...

class OAuth2Module(object):
    # ...
```

#### `exampleclass.py`

```
class ExampleClass(base_module.BaseHandler):
    def __init__(self, auth_module, ...):
        self.auth_module = auth_module
        # ...

    def foo(self):
        if self.auth_module:
            self.auth_module.bar()
```

#### `main.py`

```
# this is where ExampleClass is created
if use_option:
    # the optional dependency only really gets pulled in here
    from authmodule import AuthModule
    example_obj = ExampleClass(AuthModule())
else:
    example_obj = ExampleClass(None)

# ...
example_obj.foo()
```

Obviously this can be implemented a little differently, like moving the boilerplate from `ExampleClass` into a `DummyAuthModule`. (Can't really tell for sure seeing as it's not certain how the maybe-inherited class is used.)

Comment: Thank you. Also a good idea. I prefer the @catmur decorator solution, because it is self explaining, generic and simple.